# How to get transaction from Braintree Webhooks (SubscriptionChargedSuccessfuly)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I want to send an invoice when a client's subscription is charged. The invoice includes details from the transaction (product info and price, etc). How do I find the transaction from the WebhookNotification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

Subscription webhooks have a [subscription attribute](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/subscription/ruby#attributes). Subscriptions have a [transactions attribute](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/ruby#transactions).

In order to access the most recent transaction, you could implement something such as the following:

```
post "/webhooks" do
  webhook_notification = Braintree::WebhookNotification.parse(
    request.params["bt_signature"],
    request.params["bt_payload"]
  )
  puts "Most recent transaction: #{webhook_notification.subscription.transactions[0]}"
  return 200
end
```

For more information on handling webhooks, check out our webhook [guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/overview) and [reference](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/overview).

Comment: I use sandbox and for webhook_notification.subscription.transactions[0].id I always get id=100 for multiple different users/subscriptions. Is that something expected from sandbox env and will that be OK in prod for getting transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

```
webhook_notification.subscription.transactions.first
```

Will get the first (most recent) transaction related to that subscription.